# Haskell: extract integers from a string

Tags: haskell

Hello I have this `String`

```
"(33,18,109)"
```

How do I extract the integers from this string to apply functions on them ?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: See also [How to extract all numbers from a string in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524010/how-to-extract-all-numbers-from-a-string-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way is to use `read "(33,18,109)" :: (Int,Int,Int)`, but this is not considered a good way since it does not handle failure (for example read `"(21,3,not valid)"` and `(21,43)` would result in error.

A better way is to use the `readMaybe "(1,2,3) :: Maybe (Int,Int,Int)"`. The result uses a `Maybe` to represent possible failure:

```hs
import Text.Read

ans :: String -> Maybe (Int,Int,Int)
ans = readMaybe
```

```hs
ans "(12,53,29)" == Just (12,53,29)
ans "not a valid string" == Nothing
```

However, you might want to see how you ended up with a string in the first place. Is it because of performing IO operations (e.g. reading from a file)? If not, usually you don't have to directly deal with a string representation of something then operate on it (since this violates the layers of abstraction).

Also, there is a topic called Parser Combinator that deals with parsing in Haskell. But this is hugely irrelevant if your task is to only parse 3 numbers instead of more complicated things like parsing arithmetic expressions (e.g. `1+2*3`).

Comment: Another problem here, is that it is not said that there will be three integers. It is possible that there are for example two. Especially since the question is not clear on that point.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the most likely scenario is that OP is trying to interface with an (external) API that returns "(a,b,c)". But you are quite right, I just assumed that because OP used tuple syntax.